# PowerShell - How to programmatically determine which registry keys a Group Policy Object modifies?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, registry, group-policy

As the title, how to automatically map GPOs to their corresponding Windows registry values in PowerShell?

I am now very experienced in PowerShell, but determine which registry value is modified by a GPO with PowerShell is still a little bit too hard to me, currently I am able to use Process Monitor to create custom filters to only include activities of `mmc.exe gpedit.msc`, then use Tools->"Registry Summary" to get registry entries modified by gpedit.msc, then I can export the entries to a .csv file and import it in powershell and do further commands, but this method doesn't show which registry key is modified by a GPO, so I have to manually change a GPO and switch to "Registry Summary" to see which registry entry is modified by the last GPO change, this is very inefficient; I am aware there are some existing group policy to registry mappings, but they are incomplete.

So how can I determine which registry entry is modified by a GPO in PowerShell? Any help is appreciated.

---

### ***Update***

As far as I know, Windows Group Policy definitions are *.admx files stored in C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions folder, and the localization files that make the policy definitions be displayed in gpedit.msc are *.adml files with the same name of corresponding *.admx file stored in a subfolder named the language code of the locale (i.e. en-US) inside C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions folder, all information about the group policies should be in them, so if I can parse these files, I can map GPOs to their equivalent registry keys.

Just opened one of the .admx files in Notepad++, and found out these files are encoded in plain text, completely human readable, they are just .xml files renamed, so it's easier than I thought...

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that does this mapping thing...

---

### ***UPDATE1***

So far I have achieved these:

```
[xml]$xml=get-content C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\AppXRuntime.admx
$xml.policydefinitions.policies.policy[0].name
$xml.policydefinitions.policies.policy[0].key
```

Of course when actually running the script I will use two loops, first loop foreach .admx in folder, second loop use for $index to assign values, I can do it right now.

Just foreach loop through filenames without extension, cast C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions${filename}.admx to $xml1, and C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\en-US${filename}.adml to $xml2, use:

```
($xml2.policydefinitionresources.resources.stringtable.string | where {$_.id -eq $xml1.policydefinitions.policies.policy[$i].name})."#text"
```

To get display names, it is really simple. But the key does not contain the hivename (i.e. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE).

I have worked out this:

```
$xml.policydefinitions.categories.category.parentcategory.ref + $xml.policydefinitions.categories.category.name
```

To get path of GPO, I assume if it starts with Windows: then the key is stored in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Comment: I would say that the most reliable approach is to parse all policy definition files (*.admx and *.adm).  In those files you clearly see what each policy does. But parsing those files might be difficult Furthermore, for the title and description you need to parse the *.adml files (language-specific) as well.

Comment: Great idea! I will try to write a script that does it.

Comment: Answer to your update: As I said, it's difficult to parse and combine those files properly. The description and "display text" attributes are using placeholders, where the corresponding entry is in the adml file with the same file name (adml instead of admx). For the beginning I would suggest to analyze the following script I found: ( https://www.virtues.it/2017/03/ps-admx-translation-script/ ). But don't use datatables and all those where-object commands, which hits the performance quite hard. Use a generic list and put all lookup tables into ordered dictionaries/hashtables for fast access.

Comment: PS: Just saw the article references to a github repository: https://github.com/cognitionIT/ADMXReader